# HTTP Proxy - upstream connect error or disconnect/reset before headers. reset reason: protocol error

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

I created two spring boot application one serving APIs and another acting as a HTTP proxy to that API (which internally uses CloseableHttpClient to bounce on the another url, fetches the data adds cors and pushes back the response.)

I deployed both into GCP cloud run but when I run it locally it works but not when using the cloud run endpoint.

It resulting in error like this -

`upstream connect error or disconnect/reset before headers. reset reason: protocol error`

What it is I am messing up ?

Comment: Are you using http? If so this might be the cause of the error, as cloud run might be expecting https.

Comment: Hi @RafaelLemos No I have both services deployed on https on cloud run. Service A is consuming the app request and forwarding request with `X-Forwarded-For` & `Referer` & `Host` header to service B using ClosableHttpClient.

Comment: And do you have [end-to-end http2](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/http2#console) enabled? If so, try redeploying with the curl option `--http1.1` to disable it and let me know if it works.

Comment: @girishmahajan please let us know if the above comment helps you?